# Firefox autoupdate feature borked

Tags: firefox, updates

My Firefox installation suddenly stopped presenting automatic update prompt. (nor Help menu command have effect). So i'm stuck with v.3.6.9 while v.4.0 is out already. Please suggest where should i look for resolution.

---

Guys, please note the version No. If updater'd worked correctly, i'd have 3.6.16, so something is definitely wrong. I'd prefer to fix the issue rather than inherit to 4.x installation.

Newer findings: "Installed updated log" dialog presents me an empty list. Looks like a symptom.

Comment: Grammar Nazi Feil! It actually borked not broken :-P

Answer (score 1):

If you want Firefox 4 and are not interested in fixing the 3.x update issue, you can download it from http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/fx/.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote.  A re-install (especially a new version that uses a different default install location) should fix the problem quickly.  It will import any bookmarks and compatible extensions.

Answer (score 1):

I think Mozilla Update only works for same version numbers. So you should be able to update to Firefox 3.6.16 (I guess this is the current version number of 3.x series). My Firefox 3.x has updated itself.

To upgrade to Firefox 4, you will need to [download it](http://www.getfirefox.com/).